# Sending binary body in node.js HTTPS post

Tags: node.js

I have the following code that takes base64 string, and send it to API that accepts binary. I am getting empty response from the api call

```
    let base64String = event.base64String;
    // pass the base64 string into buffer
    let buffer = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64');

    // TODO check file type

    processImage(buffer)
        .then(result => {
            console.log("result are " + result);
            callback(result);
        }).catch(error => callback(error));


let processImage = function (buffer) {
    // get the file extension
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://<UR - not visible for privacy>',
            headers:
            {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            },
            body: buffer.toString('binary')
        };

        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) reject(error);

            console.log(body);

            resolve(body);
        });
}
```

Equivalent in postman is that I simply specify binary in body and attach file, again post call but URL is removed from pic, the header is content-type: application/octet-stream, it works in postman but not in node.js

[image]

Comment: if your working with images and files  try reading the file to an arrayBuffer then get a blob from the ABuffr, then set the post body to the blob and use the correct mime type for the type of binary photo in the body.

Comment: In Node.js `binary` encoding doesn't mean 01. Check https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings